# Issue with controlling GPIO via Flask web app

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, web-server

I am currently building a project in which I am using a Flask web app to control various different components with the pi's GPIO. The issue i am currently having is stopping the execution of code that controls the components. When a button is clicked on the web page it starts a for loop that controls a stepper motor for a certain number of iterations. Here is that code

```
for x in range(1000):
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInOne'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInTwo'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInThree'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInFour'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)

    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInOne'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInTwo'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInThree'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInFour'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)

    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInOne'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInTwo'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInThree'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInFour'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)

    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInOne'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInTwo'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInThree'], GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.001)
    GPIO.output(pins['Right Motor']['rightInFour'], GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.001)
```

Where the problem lies is that when the button is clicked, the server continues execution of that for loop until it ends. I need a way to stop the execution as soon as the stop button is clicked.

Any help and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you